# onFieldSubmitted of TextFormFeild repetitive call upon calling future function - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, future

**Scenario:**

I have a `TextFormFeild` in which user write product name to search. If the searched product is not available in the database then I want to store that searched product in the database. To do that I have the function `storeUserSearchedValue()` which is calling future function inside it.
After looking googling this problem I have found that calling future during flutter's build phase causes repetitive invocations.

How can I store the value of the searched product in the database on the `onFieldSubmitted` function without facing non-stop repetirive invocation of the function?

**Code**

Class Displaying `textfeild` and and it's `onFieldSubmitted` function.

```
class SearchProductView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchProductViewState createState() => _SearchProductViewState();
}

class _SearchProductViewState extends State<SearchProductView> {
 
storeUserSearchedValue(String _userSearchedProduct,List<Product> _productsData) {
    print("I N S I D E    storeUserSearchedValue: " + _userSearchedProduct.toString());
    int _noOfResultsOfUserProducts = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _productsData.length; i++) {
      if (_productsData[i].name.contains(_userSearchedProduct)) 
        _noOfResultsOfUserProducts++;
    }
    if (_noOfResultsOfUserProducts == 0)
      SearchviewModel().addCustomerSearchedProducts(_userSearchedProduct);
 }



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final _allProductsData = Provider.of<List<Product>>(context);

return Scaffold(
............
TextFormField(
     controller: _searchedProductText,
     onFieldSubmitted:
            storeUserSearchedValue(
                 _searchedProductText.text,
                 _allProductsData,
                ),
     onChanged: searchOperation,
    ),
)
.........
}
```

Actual logic of storing data in the database

```
class SearchviewModel extends BaseViewModel {


// -------- Below Function are adding searched product in `customer` collection

addCustomerSearchedProducts(String searchedProductText) async {
    String _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    Map<String, dynamic> custdataMap = {
      "custSearchedProducts": [searchedProductText, DateTime.now()]
    };
    await updateCustData(custdataMap, _currentUser.uid);
}


 Future<bool> updateCustData(Map<String, dynamic> dataMap, String custID) async {
    // - Dynamically adding data in the db
    dataMap.forEach(
      (key, value) async {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customer').doc(custID).set(
          {
            key: value,
          },SetOptions(merge: true),
        );
      },
    );
    return true;
  }

}
```

Video representaion of problem

[image]

Comment: did you try adding a flag and checking before calling the function again?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta What kind of check? How can I check?

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding this `(_)=>` (not this `()=>`) with `onFieldSubmitted` property of `textformfeild` while calling `storeUserSearchedValue` function stop repetative invocations.

```
onFieldSubmitted: (_)=> storeUserSearchedValue(_searchedProductText.text,_allProductsData),
```

The above code snippet worked fine!

I'm not quite sure what is the reason behind it though